# Platform specific CornerRadius on <Frame> Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to assign different `CornerRadius` on `iOS` and `Android` like following:

```
<Frame
    HasShadow="false"
    Padding="10"
    BackgroundColor="Red">
    <Frame.CornerRadius>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
            <On
                Platform="iOS">20</On>
            <On
                Platform="Android">30</On>
        </OnPlatform>
    </Frame.CornerRadius>
    <Label
        Text="Hello World" />
</Frame>
```

But getting a

> Cannot assign property "CornerRadius": Property does not exists, or is not assignable, or mismatching type between value and property

I've tried `x:TypeArguments="Thickness"` and `x:TypeArguments="x:Int32"`. Decompiling the Assembly it appears `CornerRadius` is of type `float`. However, there is no `Float` property in `x namespace`, I mean `x:TypeArguments="x:Float"` doesn't exists.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or this is a bug?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `CornerRadius` type is a `Single`:

```
<Frame HasShadow="true" OutlineColor="Red">
    <Frame.CornerRadius>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Single">
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="20"/>
            <On Platform="Android" Value="30"/>
        </OnPlatform>
    </Frame.CornerRadius>
    <Frame.Content>
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </Frame.Content>
</Frame>
```

Comment: On Xamarin.Forms 4.5+, the x:TypeArguments property should be set to "Int32"

Answer (score 1):

Well I fell there is a syntax error here do something like this :

```
<Frame.CornerRadius>
 <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Single">
        <OnPlatform.Platforms>
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="20" />
            <On Platform="Android" Value="30" />
            <On Platform="UWP" Value="30" />
        </OnPlatform.Platforms>
    </OnPlatform>
 </Frame.CornerRadius>
```

Try this and in case it doesn't work kindly revert.

Comment: Thanks buddy, but thats not the case, syntax is correct. However, I did try your solution too. The error was `Type CornerRadius not found`

Comment: That is because I assumed that you would add it inside a parent frame and not just like that without anything

Comment: For the others looking at it... UWP = x:Int32, the challenge here is to support 2 type...  do it by defining a a value of the correcttype and refer it in the onplatform